# Configure log formats in PyCharm

Tags: python, logging, pycharm

I was using the "logging" module in a python file and I've created a log file as a file handler. Everything goes well, but in the log file there is a blue bar at the top that says "Log format not recognized".

[Screenshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItNj5.png)

[Screenshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4BnM.png)

How can I configure the log format?